# How to use jest to test a function's return value(array)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

Here is my function to recursively loop through a object:

```
const helper = (obj,list) =>{
    for (var property in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(typeof obj[property] == "object") {     
                helper(obj[property],list);
            }else {
                if (property === "$ref"){
                    if(!list.includes(obj[property])){
                        list.push(obj[property]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
};
```

The object is simple, please see below:

```
{
    "person": {
         "properties": {
             "sex":{
                "type":"string"
             },
             "name": {
                "$ref": "#/person/properties/sex" 
             }
          }
     }
}
```

The the `helper` will finally return a list `['#/person/properties/sex']`

To run the code, just do `helper(some_obj,[])`

Here is my jest test code:

```
describe('helper function test',  () =>{
    it('should return a list', () =>{
        const mock = jest.fn((obj,[]) => helper(obj,[]));
        const list = mock(obj,[]);
        expect(list).toMatch(['something']);
    });
});
```

I have also tried:

```
describe('helper function test',  () =>{
    it('should return a list', () =>{
        const list = helper(obj, []);
        expect(list).toMatch(['something']);
    });
});
```

The jest tells me the `expect` object is a array but it's value is `[]`, which means empty. Actually I did a manually test for `helper` function in the function file, the return has no problem, which is what I expect.

One thing to mention, I use this `helper` inside of a promise later, I do not know the issue is related to promise, since the promise function has not called. I even tried to comment out the promise function, still no luck.

Would someone tells me how to get the real result from the jest? I would really appreciate any helps here! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use jest.fn in here. If you want to test your function, you can do this:

```
describe('helper function test',  () =>{
    it('should return a list', () =>{
        const list = helper(obj, []);
        expect(list).toEqual(['something']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I should update my question. I have tried this methods before, still give me empty array.

Comment: I edited my answer, did you try with equal instead of toMatch ?

Comment: Yes, but no luck. I hope this is not some dark magic happens here. @Axnyff

Comment: Can you update your question with the object? If this test is failing it means your function is returning an empty array

Comment: It works for me, either in jest or in a standalone script. Something must be missing from your question. Can you do a minimal reproduction with all the code ? I have no idea where helper and obj come from in your example

Comment: Thank you @Axnyff it works after I extract this function to a new file. I may check line by line to figure out what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2023, **Jest** version-`"jest": "^29.5.0"` you can use `toBeInstanceOf()` to check the type.

---

If you want to check the return type of a function you can use the syntax below.

- Just replace `yourFunc` with the proper name of your function
- Replace `funcParams` with the parameters your function receives.

  ```
   import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals"
    import { yourFunc } from "../yourFunc"

    describe("Test function - yourFunc", () => {
      test("expects that yourFunc returns an array type", () => {
        const returnValue = yourFunc(funcParams)
        expect(returnValue).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
      })
    })
  ```